# Is it possible to code Jquery or Javascript in global.asax file

Tags: c#, asp.net, global-asax

Hi all i am having a requirement i.e i will have image icons on my form where i have to show tool tips when i hover the mouse on that icon. Assume that i have my controls as follows on a form

```
    Bank Name   Textbox   Helpicon(when i mouse over on this i would like to display the tooltip from global.asax file)
```

Like that i have another form with same controls there also when i mouse over on the image icon i would like to display the same help file as tooltip for the help file.

I have done this with `Jquery` but my manager is asking to show the help text from the `global.asax` file.. so is it possible to show the help text when i mouse over the icon from `global.asax` file. Can any one provide sample code..

Comment: @GhyathSerhal: His English isn't the best but I think I got what he is looking for.

Comment: @Vivekh Please improve your English and try to explain what you need better.

Answer (score 1):

global.asax is not meat for this as it is pure server side code.
I assume you can use a master page that will always include the script you have done to display the tooltip.
You can just need to mark the help icon with a class and perhaps display the value that is written in the alt property (it makes sense since when javascript is disabled/not available people will still be able to view the help text)

Answer (score 0):

Use a master page and put your jquery and other javascript there.

Comment: Never ever incudescripts in the html file nless youreally know what you are doing. He clearly doesn't. Please edit accordingly.